# how to create a basic setting page using xamarin xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How to create a basic setting page in xamarin, where each row are clickable button or link that open up different page in screen? Below is a screenshot of what I am trying to create:

after doing some research on google, seem like I can do this by listview, collectionview or tableview...

below, I tried using a collection list but its only 1 catorgery. in screen shot there are two. also border width is smaller than screen on each row

```
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding CardTypeList}">
            <!-- Body -->
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- Body -->
                    <Grid Padding="0">
                        <Frame CornerRadius="3" BorderColor="#f2f4f5" HasShadow="True">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label VerticalOptions="Center"
                                               FontSize="16" 
                                               Text="{Binding .}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <!-- Header -->
            <CollectionView.Header>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Official ID"  
                           TextColor="Black" 
                           VerticalOptions="Center" 
                           FontSize="16" 
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           Padding="10,10,0,10"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </CollectionView.Header>
        </CollectionView>
```

[image]

Comment: use Grouping - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping

Comment: do you know if its easier if i use tableview or its all the same in term of creating same look?

Comment: "easier" is a matter of opinion.  TableView is not very versatile compared to CollectionView.

Comment: got it, make sense, ill stick to collection. thanks